# strange string convertion using form helper

Tags: html, cakephp, encoding, cakephp-2.0

I have following code:

```
<?php 

     $select_options = array();
     foreach($delivery_options as $option)
     {
        $select_options[$option->getDeviceId()] = $option->getDeviceName();
        echo $select_options[$option->getDeviceId()]; 
     }

     echo $this->Form->input('default_device', array( 
        'type' => 'select', 
        'options' => $select_options, 
        'value' => $default_device,
        'label' => '', 
    ));


?>
```

In foreach loop every echo returns this:
`abc'abc`
In html source code it looks like this `abc&#39;abc`

and then in select input: `abc&#39;abc`
In html source code: `abc&amp;#39;abc`

It means that `&` char from `abc&#39;abc` was converted to it's html encoding - `&amp` - but how did it happen?

I also tried htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() but this still doesnt help...

Comment: using value in inputs like this is as wrong as it can get. you destroy the form on posts (it will reset all the time). set the default values correctly using "default" or even better using the controller - see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Comment: true, but in this case `$default_device` is not default value for select but user's default device - I read it from `$this-Auth-user('default_device')`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The select input type allows for a special $option attribute called
>   'escape' which accepts a bool and determines whether to HTML entity
>   encode the contents of the select options. Defaults to true.

Try setting it to false.

```
echo $this->Form->input('default_device', array( 
        'type' => 'select', 
        'options' => $select_options,
        'escape' => false, // like so
        'value' => $default_device,
        'label' => '', 
));
```